# How to setup .htaccess with subfolder and pointed to dist folder

Tags: vue.js, .htaccess

**Objective: .htaccess config that pointed the index.html inside dist folder**

Folder in root directory: api, main and admin.

inside main folder there is a folder name call **dist** where inside are files that compiled by VITE like index.html, assets, img and etc.

This is my current .htaccess config

```
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
 Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```